# How do I scrape nested data using selenium and Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I basically want to scrape **Litigation Paralegal** under `<h3 class="Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold">` and **Olswang** under `<span class="pv-entity__secondary-title Sans-15px-black-55%">`, but I can't see to get to it. Here's the HTML at code:

```
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info">

<h3 class="Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold">Litigation Paralegal</h3>

<h4>
  <span class="visually-hidden">Company Name</span>
  <span class="pv-entity__secondary-title Sans-15px-black-55%">Olswang</span>
</h4>


  <div class="pv-entity__position-info detail-facet m0"><h4 class="pv-entity__date-range Sans-15px-black-55%">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>
      <span>Feb 2016 – Present</span>
    </h4><h4 class="pv-entity__duration de Sans-15px-black-55% ml0">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Employment Duration</span>
        <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item">1 yr 2 mos</span>
      </h4><h4 class="pv-entity__location detail-facet Sans-15px-black-55% inline-block">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Location</span>
      <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item">London, United Kingdom</span>
    </h4></div>

</div>
```

And here is what I've been doing at the moment with selenium in my code:

```
if tree.xpath('//*[@class="pv-entity__summary-info"]'):

   experience_title =  tree.xpath('//*[@class="Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold"]/h3/text()')
   print(experience_title)

   experience_company = tree.xpath('//*[@class="pv-position-entity__secondary-title pv-entity__secondary-title Sans-15px-black-55%"]text()')
   print(experience_company)
```

My output:
Experience title : `[]`
`[]`

Answer (score 0):

Your `XPath` expressions are incorrect:

- `//*[@class="Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold"]/h3/text()` means *text content of `h3` which is `child` of element with class name attribute `"Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold"`*. Instead you need

  `//h3[@class="Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold"]/text()`

  which means *text content of `h3` element with class name attribute `"Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold"`*
- In `//*[@class="pv-position-entity__secondary-title pv-entity__secondary-title Sans-15px-black-55%"]text()` you forgot a slash before `text()` (you need `/text()`, not just `text()`). And also target `span` has no class name `pv-position-entity__secondary-title`. You need to use

  `//span[@class="pv-entity__secondary-title Sans-15px-black-55%"]/text()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get both of these easily with CSS selectors and I find them a lot easier to read and understand than XPath.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.pv-entity__summary-info > h3").text
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.pv-entity__summary-info span.pv-entity__secondary-title").text
```

`.` indicates class name
`>` indicates child (one level below only)
 indicates a descendant (any levels below)

Here are some references to get you started.

[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[CSS Selectors Tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

[Advanced CSS Selectors](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/)